# Read file to vector of vectors, out of range error

Tags: c++

I'm working on a program that solves mazes for a project. The requirements are that the maze text file is able to vary in length in any way, and that it must be read to a vector of vectors of characters.

So far I've created a program that should work in my mind at least, there's a while loop that adds a row to the vector for each line in the file. And I'm using a simple for loop with pushback using the .at() operator on the current line of the file. At the bottom I have a simple for loop to display the first row. The problem is that I keep getting an out of range error with the vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



int main(){
    ifstream file;
    string fileName;
    string Line;
    vector<vector<char>> Maze;
    cout << "Enter the maze file name and extension: " << endl;
    cin >> fileName;
    file.open(fileName);

    while (getline(file, Line)) {
        int rowNumber = 0;
        vector<char> row;
        Maze.push_back(row);
        for (int i = 0; i < Line.size(); i++) {
            Maze[rowNumber].push_back(Line.at(i));
        }
        rowNumber++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << Maze[0][i];
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using a test file that has 5 rows of five characters, no whitespace. I expect that the program will print out the first row of the file, instead I get a Debug Assertion failed error and states that the vector subscript is out of range. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Where do you get the crash? What are the indexes used there? Is it for `Line.at(i)` when you read from the file, or is it from the loop where you output? Run in a debugger to catch the exception as and when it happens.

Comment: Furthermore, you define `rowNumber` *inside* the file-reading loop, which means it will *always* be zero. Something else you would have noticed if you [debugged your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Lastly, you could easily use the iterator-overload of the [`std::vector` constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). Or use [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) to simply do `Maze.emplace_back(Line.begin(), Line.end())` as the only line inside the loop.

Comment: Your code works. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29b8b7ce78242906

Comment: _"states that"_ -- this phrasing is something to avoid when asking for debugging help. Don't paraphrase. Copy-and-paste the exact error message. Also tell us on which line the the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

There are several comments to your code.

It works as it is shown. It does not produce a runtime error, but also not the expected result.

The propblem is that you do always set the variable `rowNumber` to 0 every time at the beginning of the while loop. `rowNumber++;` at the end of the while will have no effect. So, you are alwyas adding chars to `Maze[0]`.

That is your semantic error.

YOur runtime error came, when you tried to access `Maze[1][i]`

Then, your code could be drastically shortened by using C++ algorithms. See:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>


std::istringstream testDataFile(
R"#(00000
11111
22222
33333
44444
)#");



// This is a proxy to read a complete line with the extractor operator
struct CompleteLineAsVectorOfChar {
    // Overloaded Extractor Operator
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, CompleteLineAsVectorOfChar& cl) {
        std::string s{}; cl.completeLine.clear();  std::getline(is, s); 
        std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(cl.completeLine));
        return is; }

    operator std::vector<char>() const { return completeLine; }  // Type cast operator for expected value
    std::vector<char> completeLine{};
};


int main()
{
    // Read complete source file into maze, by simply defining the variable and using the range constructor
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> maze { std::istream_iterator<CompleteLineAsVectorOfChar>(testDataFile), std::istream_iterator<CompleteLineAsVectorOfChar>() };

    // Debug output:  Copy all data to std::cout
    std::for_each(maze.begin(), maze.end(), [](const std::vector<char> & l) {std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, " ")); std::cout << '\n'; });

    return 0;
}
```

But this is not the end. A `std::vector<char>`has no advantage over a string. You can work nearly have all the same functionality as a `std::vector<char>`. That is an improvement in design. The code would then look more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream testDataFile(
R"#(00000
11111
22222
33333
44444
)#");

int main()
{
    // Read complete source file into maze, by simply defining the variable and using the range constructor
    std::vector<std::string> maze{ std::istream_iterator<std::string>(testDataFile), std::istream_iterator<std::string>() };

    // Debug output:  Copy all data to std::cout
    std::copy(maze.begin(), maze.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

This is the by far more simpler solution. And it will serve your needs as well.

Please note: I used a istringstream for reading data, becuase I do not have a file on SO. But it is of cause the same as using any other stream (like an ifstream).

Hope this helps . . .